# My bootstrap icons logo is appearing square

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-icons

I have included my Boostrapmin and bootstrap icon CSS as well.

```
                <i class="bi bi-play-circle"></i>
```

this icon I am trying to use. but it appears as square. css is applied I can see it in inspect element of google chrome.

Comment: How are you referencing the icons? On CDN or a local link?

Comment: locally I have added css file

Comment: Then is most likely because you haven't included the font files locally

Comment: but there is no files on bootstrap website to out in fonts

Comment: Yes there is.. in the /fonts folder when you download the from the source on GitHub... why don't you simply use the CDN?

Comment: That's the requirement of project that's why

Comment: I will definitely include that fonts folder, Thank you : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included my Boostrapmin and bootstrap icon CSS as well.

```
                <i class="bi bi-play-circle"></i>
```

this icon I am trying to use. but it appears as square. css is applied I can see it in inspect element of google chrome.

So, Here I am writing a solution Thanks to [@zim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/zim) for help.

---

Step1:
Download Bootstrap icon CSS file, **bootstrap-icons.css**
Link it in your project
--By including in **CSS** file
**OR**
--By linking in **HTML** file.

After that download the fonts folder from the Bootstrap icons git repository.
--Now open **bootstrap-icons.css**
And you will find code like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
  src: url("../fonts/bootstrapfonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2") //Match this file path format("woff2"),
    url("../fonts/bootstrapfonts/bootstrap-icons.woff") //Match this file pathformat("woff");
}
```

-**bootstrap-icons.woff2** and **bootstrap-icons.woff** make sure you link it properly with **bootstrap-icons.css** file.
**And boom you are good to go.. :)**

---